# How would I do reporting from Azure RoleEntryPoint whether its running or not

Tags: c#, azure, distributed-computing

Im creating a worker role that i would like to know, within my SQL data layer, if its running.

I register the role when `onStart` is called and I am considering to unregister it in the `onStop` method. Can i count on `onStop` is being called? or should i make it report its alive every 10min and have another application check that its live and if not, set the unit as offline?

How would people get around this problem about distributed programs?

Is it possible to get a Unique Guid for a specific instance of a worker/web role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heartbeat is the right way to do this. You can't guarantee that `OnStop` will be called, because hardware can fail suddenly.

Comment: Thanks. What solutions do people use to clean up dead instances?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: If my database is populated with info when a instance register itself, then it do a heartbeat every now and then. Can the database trigger something to cleanup itself for instances that have not reported alive for let say an hour.

Comment: When you query your database, simply include a WHERE clause that only returns instances with a heartbeat < 1min ago or so.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't count on `OnStop()` being called. If the node where your instance runs crashes `OnStop()` is not called. If an exception is propagated outside `Run()` or `OnStart()` of your instance `OnStop()` is not called. Those are the top cases I can think of right now, perhaps there're more of them. The bottom line is you can't count on `OnStop()` being called.

You should use heartbeats stored in some persistent storage - like SQL Azure or Azure Queues or whatever else. When you want to do "cleanup" or "reprocessing" you just select stuff that has no heartbeats for some reasonably long period of time. For example, live entities will issue heartbeats every one minute, then you can consider anything that had no heartbeats for five minutes or more dead.

Comment: Thank you also for the clarification.